# Visual Studio 2005: How do I find which build step in the .sln creates a specific file

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, devenv

I am trying to automate a build by calling `devenv.exe my_Solution.sln /rebuild "Project Name"` but am having a problem because a build.cmd file which is crucial to the build, is not getting created in the expected location.  When I open the Solution manually and choose Build -> Rebuild it works fine and the file is created.  How do I track down where the failure is occurring, or find out where in the build this file is created?  Mind you I am not a developer and do not know Visual Studio well at all.  I am a sysadmin trying to help a developer.

Comment: Look through the prebuild events.  Probably doesn't work because it forgets to specify the full path and the default directory is wrong.

Comment: Could you tell me how to look through the prebuild events? :)

Comment: Why don't you just ask the dev, he knows what that means.

Comment: They aren't available right now and I wanted to get past this issue.  Is your user name a chess reference?

Comment: OK, I've looked through a bunch of the projects in the solution explorer, chose project settings and viewed the pre and post build steps and I see nothing, no mention of build.cmd.